# Using next.js with yarn workspaces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Ran into a complication today with project structure like this

```
packages
  /app
    pages/
    package.json
  /ui-kit
    pages/
    package.json
  /shared
.babelrc
package.json
```

root lvl package json defines `workspaces: [packages/*]` where `app` and `ui-kit` are both nextjs apps.

I have following script in root lvl package.json

```
"dev:app": "next packages/app",
"dev:ui-kit": "next packages/ui-kit"
```

both of these worked fine until I introduced `shared` folder, which essentially contains some functions / components etc... that are re-used between packages. As soon as I include it into either `app` or `ui-kit` I get error like this

in ./packages/shared/index.js

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:21) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type. | import React from
>   'react' |  | export default () => Hello shared! |

So it looks like nextjs is not applying any loaders to anything outside the folder where it was pointed at. Is there a solution to fix this somehow? i.e. start next from root folder but point it to different entry files somehow based on different script commands?

Comment: If you set the root level with NODE_PATH?

Comment: Doesn't solve it, I think next needs to somehow run inside packages, yet point to specific apps

Answer (score 20):

Since **NextJs 11**, there's a new experimental option called [externalDir](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/22867) which works pretty well and does not require the use of next-transpile-modules.

For clarity let's make a step by step howto, it might look a long process but once you get it, it's pretty easy (actually 3 steps)

---

#### 1. Yarn V3 (optional)

For improved experience I suggest to upgrade [yarn to v3+](https://dev.to/arcanis/yarn-3-0-performances-esbuild-better-patches-e07) (`yarn set version 3.0.2 && yarn plugin import workspace-tools`) and edit the generated config `.yarnrc.yml` similar to this one:

```yaml
# Yarn 2+ supports pnp or regular node_modules installs. Use node-modules one.
nodeLinker: node-modules
nmMode: hardlinks-local
plugins:
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools.cjs
    spec: "@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools"
yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.0.2.cjs
```

PS: you might want to add this to `.gitignore` too

```
.yarn/*
!.yarn/patches
!.yarn/releases
!.yarn/plugins
!.yarn/sdks
!.yarn/versions
.pnp.*
```

**Why ?** Cause you'll get the possibility to use the [workspace: alias protocol](https://yarnpkg.com/features/protocols#workspace). *(available in pnpm too)*

---

#### 2. Strict workspace topology (optional)

I suggest to be strict about what packages depends on (to have clear boundaries). It's not an absolute requirement, but a good practice that might avoid *hard to debug* situations.

To help the package manager, I suggest to properly declare your dependencies and their boundaries per app/packages.

In other words each package/app had its own package.json where you explicitly add the deps they need (not in the root package.json)

Following your example,

```
apps/
packages
  /app
    package.json (app depend on ui-kit through yarn workspace: alias)
    tsconfig.json (we will add typescript path aliases there too) 
    next.config.js
  /ui-kit
    package.json
package.json (do not put nextjs as dep here, only in app)
```

An example for root `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "monorepo",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"  // Enable package discovery in packages/* directory.
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "7.0.2", // Only what's needed for monorepo management
  }
```

An example for `packages/app/package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "16.10.1",
    "@types/react": "17.0.29",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.9",
    "typescript": "4.4.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // Assuming the name of packages/ui-kit is ui-kit,
    // we explicitly declare the dependency on it through
    // workspace: alias (package-manager perspective)
    "ui-kit": "workspace:*",
    "next": "11.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
  }
}
```

**Why ?** That way you won't fall into weird problems with conflicting deps.

---

### 3. Typescript aliases

Even if you're not using typescript, NextJs will read the `tsconfig.json` and look for [typescript path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) configuration. If you're not aware of what it is... it's simply a configuration where you declare (one more time) your deps. Nextjs will convert them to what it uses under the hood to compile deps (ie: [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver) and probably later swc).

Following your example, just edit a `./packages/app/tsconfig.json` in this way

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // here baseUrl is set at ./src (good practive), can
    // be set to '.'  
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      // Declare deps here (keep them in sync with what
      // you defined in the package.json)
      // PS: path are relative to baseUrl
      "ui-kit/*": ["../../ui-kit/src/*"],
      // if you have a barrel in ui-lib 
      "ui-kit": ["../../ui-kit/src/index"],
    }
  },
}
```

**Why ?** More a limitation between tooling (package managers and paths have different perspectives)

---

### 4. Nextjs configuration

In `packages/app/nextjs.config.js`, enable the [externalDir](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/22867) config (currently in experimental but works pretty well, [feedback thread here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/26420))

```js
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    // this will allow nextjs to resolve files (js, ts, css)
    // outside packages/app directory. 
    externalDir: true,
  },
};
export default nextConfig;
```

PS: for older nextjs versions, it's totally possible to do the same through custom webpack config. Ask if you need an example.

---

### What you'll get

In your app you should be able to import your ui-kit like this:

```js
import { Button } from 'ui-kit';
// or
import Avatar from 'ui-kit/components/Avatar'
```

The beauty of it is that **fast refresh will work out of the box** (no build necessary). It's fast, you don't need NX (+ the pricey nx.cloud), rush or anything...

Nextjs will simply import the files, build them on demand and even cache them in it's own optimized cache (especially fast with webpack 5 and can be enabled on CI too)...

If you like more information, I maintain an example repository will a full lifecycle perspective (ci, github action, linters, deploys...) on this repo: https://github.com/belgattitude/nextjs-monorepo-example.

PS: Follow also yarn 3+ development and versions [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry), they're doing a great job nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. May I know how TypeScript aliases work with `package.json` dependencies in this case? Does Next.js import the packages based on the defined TypeScript aliases or the workspace protocol? I can't really figure out why we need both steps even after I set up a monorepo successfully.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that code outside of the next folder is not transpiled by Babel. This is because the `.babelrc` file is not taken into account, even if it is at the root of your code.

However if you instead use a `babel.config.js` file (as recommended since version 7 of Babel) and put it at the root of your code (effectively replacing the `.babelrc` file), you can use this plugin:

https://github.com/josephluck/next-plugin-custom-babel-config

I've done that and it works perfectly !

Comment: This is the million dollar answer. Wish I could upvote 10x. Thanks so much.

Comment: It seems that it does not work with Next 11. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Things have changed a lot since, you don't need any babel customization since long and recently released nextjs 11 have an option that works pretty well for monorepo. For an explanation see the howto's in https://github.com/belgattitude/nextjs-monorepo-example. By the way yarn 3+ and pnpm supports workspace: protocol ("my-shared-lib": "workspace:*"). Much cleaner

Answer (score 5):

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51137950/using-next-js-with-yarn-workspaces/55748411#55748411) didn't work for me with Next.js 9.2+.  I had to use a forked package instead called [next-transpile-modules](https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules).

All you really have to do is `yarn add next-transpile-modules` into each of your packages, then add/edit a `next.config.js` with the following:

```
// next.config.js
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['somemodule', 'and-another']); // pass the modules you would like to see transpiled

module.exports = withTM();
```

You probably don't even need to a `babel.config.js` into your root directory anymore if you want to use the Next.js defaults.

The way the package works is by implementing a custom Webpack config, [as described in the official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config), to tell webpack to watch the directories of the modules you defined in the `next.config.js` above.

Answer (score 4):

Try add this to your next.config.js to enable compile typescript files outside the next root folder:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ... other settings
  experimental: {
    externalDir: true,
  },
}
```

Credit goes to: https://github.com/belgattitude/nextjs-monorepo-example#step-33-next-config