# Should I use commonjs or es module for yarn workspace sub packages for next.js proejct?

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, yarn-workspaces

I'm building Next.js monorepo project with TS, yarn workspace.

For example, I have two packages in yarn workspace, `/web` and `/api`. `/web` is a next.js project and `/api` is a shared subpackage that is used by `/web`.

```
/my-project  <-- project root
  package.json
  /web
    src/
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
    next.config.js
  /api
    src/  <-- rootDir 
    dist/  <--  outDir
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
  ...
```

```
// /my-project/package.json
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "web",
    "api"
  ],
}
// /web/packcage.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@api": "workspace:*"
  }
}
// /api/packcage.json
{ 
  "name": "@api"
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
}
// /api/tsconfing.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "module": "ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "ES6",
  },
}
```

From `/api`'s tsconfig, TS creates transpiled result which has es6 module system.(`"module": "ES6"`)

As nextjs does not support external packages built with ES module, I expected that `/api` package does not work in `/web` project. However, it works well.

Why this can be possible?

When I tried to use some packages which use ES module(built only for browser), I met some errors something like `unexpected token: export`. At that time, I have to transpile them
manually by using `next-transpile-modules` and then it resolved the issue. But, in this case, nextjs work with es module package without any issue. Did I misunderstand something about this?

Answer (score 1):

NextJs 11.1+ has an experimental option to support esm. The feedback thread is available [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/27876).

```
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    // Prefer loading of ES Modules over CommonJS
    // @link {https://nextjs.org/blog/next-11-1#es-modules-support|Blog 11.1.0}
    // @link {https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/27876|Discussion}
    esmExternals: true,
    // Experimental monorepo support
    // @link {https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/22867|Original PR}
    // @link {https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/26420|Discussion}
    externalDir: true,
  }
}
export default nextConfig;
```

ESM generally requires more than just "modules": "es6" in config... But as you noticed, I realized that some esm packages like '@sindrehorsus' ones where working without the experimental flag.

That said setting the experimental.esmExternals to true will solve most edge cases and should makes next-transpile-modules obsolete.

Note that generally I tend to set "modules" to "esnext" rather than "es6" to be inline to what nextjs recommends.

PS: If it helps, you can have a look this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69554480/5490184 or the https://github.com/belgattitude/nextjs-monorepo-example.

Comment: This was made the default in Next 12: https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12#es-modules-support-and-url-imports